# Div with sticky height and bottom

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want a div to stick to both top and bottom while being responsive on all sides.

I have a view consisting of 4 divs and 3 of them works well in responsive layout but in one I have a chat window (bottom/left) that doesn't have a very good height response. 
Below you can see the 4 divs in full view and it's looking the way that I want it to look:[image]

But once I start, either moving the side of the inspector to the left or look on a mobile device, the chat window reveals it has a solid height and leaves empty space below it (it sticks nicely to the top at least):
[image]

I can't seem to get around this problem (stuck for a week now); if I change the current viewport height (vh) to more it will only disappear underneath the screen and if I use % nothing happens. Here is a piece of the actual chat css:

```
#chatlioWidgetPlaceholder{
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 10000;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 5px;
  font-family: input;
}
```

...but once again, vh or % doesn't work out on this one either. Does anyone understand my problem?

I believe it could be something with the height of the top parent div because it doesn't stretch to the bottom (blue marked) and therefore can't grow:
[image]

I placed the HTML and CSS in https://jsfiddle.net/3chdp873/2/
I stripped the syntax from other divs for easier readability but if needed, just let me know :)

Comment: Your jsfiddle doesn't work, please put all your divs too so we can have a global view of it, you want the div#chatlioWidgetPlaceholder to be responsive too ?

Comment: I have updated the fiddle now https://jsfiddle.net/3chdp873/2/ 

The thing is that the chatdiv's bottom should be touching the bottom of the screen no matter the size.

Comment: You are required to post your minimal, relevant markup and code here that shows the problem, not some third-party site where the code may disappear tomorrow. Images aren't good enough either.

Comment: ok, updated fiddle...again https://jsfiddle.net/3chdp873/4/
But this fiddle will never work nonetheless because it's a massive project with iframes etc. and other included libraries that I don't think any online code editor can solve. So I hope someone here is a skilled code reader and might understand Bootstraps (or mine?) behavior

Comment: So what exactly do you want? to remove the space at the bottom ?

Comment: @TirthrajBarot - Yes! That the whole text field (+ input field) for the chat stretches down to the bottom and stays there despite resizing